# Check if the currently opened item is a folder or a document in EditForm.aspx

Tags: 2013, document-library, content-editor-web-part, edit-form

We have added a content editor webpart to `EditForm.aspx` for document library. In the CEWP, there's a JS filed. We need to execute different code when a folder is getting edited (like renaming the folder) and when file metadata is edited.

How can we check if the currently opened item is a folder or a document in `EditForm.aspx`? We can use the ID field in the URL and check using REST API or CSOM but I would like to avoid server calls for efficiency purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use out of the box object `WPQ1FormCtx` or `WPQ2FormCtx`. I have seen former in SharePoint Online and the later in SP2013 on prem. The property you are interested in is `WPQ1FormCtx.ItemAttributes.FsObjType`. If it is 1, the the object being edited is Folder. Attaching the screenshot from my SharePoint tenant.
[image: Folder]

You can also refere to this [link](http://bit.ly/2E8wioR). Here I had used `WPQ2FormCtx` in SP 2013

Comment: Thanks. I found another way to implement it. Posted another answer. But your approach seems to be better as it provides a few other details which developer might need in future.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative approach to Nadeem's answer.

When SharePoint opens the `EditForm.aspx` it sends the `ContentTypeId` in the URL parameters. From [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543822(v=office.14).aspx) I was able to find out that `ContentTypeId` for folder starts with `0x0120`. With that in hand I was able to check and code according to folder or a document.

Comment: Remember that user can still eidt the item/folder by having a Url upto .../EditForm.aspx?ID=5. In this case the Only parameter in the query string is ID of the item